Schengen Visa Itinerary Change
I have a Portugal short-stay Schengen visa for this Fall for tourism, and in my itinerary I included flying into Lisbon and then flying out of Spain.
If my itinerary were to change such that I was flying both in and out of Spain, but on the same exact dates, would my visa still be valid?

Yes, if you still spend most of the time in Portugal.
You can change the details of your trip after the visa was granted if the premise remains unchanged and if the changes came genuinely after the visa was granted. You should avoid giving the appearance of 'visa-shopping' (that mmeans misrepresenting your itinerary so that another consulate would be responsible for your application).
Your planned change would not affect that you are still goint to Portugal. On arrival in Spain, you would have plans and documents to show that you are immediately going to Portugal, and if asked you can show them.

Even if the change is because of blatantly obvious visa shopping, the visa remains literally valid until an officer revokes or annuls it.  Changing one's itinerary doesn't invalidate the visa, but it increases the probability of an officer deciding to invalidate it.

Some countries (mostly Eastern European) are extremely strict with changes, actively monitor hotel bookings and in extreme cases may cancel visas just because one spends one less night than initially planned in the country of application. I don't think Portugal is in this situation, though, and if the nights spend in Portugal do not change, it's definitely not a problem.

The Answer assumes that Portugal remains the "main destination" of the OP's travel. This may or may not be true, as we don't know what's planned for the time period before and after the sojourn in Portugal, nor how those before-and-after times weigh against the time in Portugal.
